# What is the meaning of $i$ in $(b_n \quad b_{n-1} \quad \cdots \quad b_0)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, notation

What is the meaning of $i$ in the following?

> $$
> (b_n  \quad b_{n-1} \quad \cdots \quad b_0) \tag 1
> $$
>   $i = n-1, n-2, \dots, 0$

Comment: $i$ is the subscript. It's just a convenient way to allow you to index a particular $b$

Comment: It is an index, whose meaning is determined by the context of a particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

i is the reversed list of indices of the sequence. For example if $n=2$, then the sequence becomes $(b_2 \ b_1 \ b_0)$, so $i = 2, 1, 0$